# Permission denied (publickey,password) on SSH connection when run as a service

Tags: ssh, systemd, rsync, services

I have a bash script, `/home/localuser/backup-script.sh`, with this snippet inside of it:

```
rsync -avzh \
  -e "ssh -i /home/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519" \
  /home/localuser/backups/file-to-backup.gz \
  remoteuser@myhost.com:/home/remoteuser/backups
```

If I run it directly from shell, everything works like a charm, while if I run it through a systemd service I configured, I get the error `remoteuser@myhost.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).`

This is the service (`/etc/systemd/system/backup.service`) I configured:

```
[Unit]
Description=Trigger script to perform backup

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=localuser
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/localuser/backup-script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I usually run it via a timer, but I also get the same error if I start it directly via `sudo systemctl start backup.service`

The ssh service is correctly setup, as confirmed by the success I have running the script directly, or also by launching `ssh remoteuser@myhost.com`.

I cannot figure out what is going on... any clue?

Additional info: I get same error replacing `rsync` with `scp`

---

**Edit:**

Following the Stewart's comment I tried to directly launch the script by running this command `env -i /bin/bash --norc --noprofile backup-script.sh` and in this case I'm prompted for the ssh key passphrase, so the problem is exactly what Stewart's comments are pointing to.

To work-around the problem with a simple solution (so avoiding to add `ssh-agent` as service, automatic keys loading, and automatic passphrase entering on boot), I changed the `rsync` command in my script, replacing the second line (`-e ...`) with this one: `--rsh="/usr/bin/sshpass -p remoteuser_pwd ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l remoteuser"`:

The result is similar: if I launch it directly, it works fine. If I launch it via the service it doesn't work: but this time with no errors, it simply hangs. And if I launch it by `env -i /bin/bash --norc --noprofile backup-script.sh` it hangs too, in the same way.

Changing the `backup.service` by adding `--login` in this way `ExecStart=/bin/bash --login /home/localuser/backup-script.sh` won't solve the issue.

Comment: Do you always use the username `remoteuser` and the private key `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` with that host?  If so, you can simplify your rsync command by creating a `~/.ssh/config` file with a clause associating the username and private key file with that host.

Comment: Have you verified that systemd is running your script as `localuser` and not as another user who can't read the private key file?  Perhaps add a command to check, such as `touch /tmp/backup.service.test.$$` in the script before the rsync command...

Comment: I would say it is verified, since in the `localuser`'s home a file is created by the same script, and the owner is correctly set to `localuser`

Comment: Just a thought, could there be something ssh related in one of your bash configurations?  To test that hypothesis, try running this from your shell `/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/localuser/backup-script.sh`.  If you reproduce the problem from your interactive terminal, then we know where to start looking.

Comment: If you have something in `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile`, then add `/bin/bash --login ...` to read those.  If you have something in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc`, then consider moving that to one of the previous files.

Comment: @Stewart Thanks to your suggestions I did new attempts and edited my question

Comment: I have two more ideas. First:  is your ssh-key password-protected?  It may be that it is password-protected and therefore needs authentication from an agent to be unlocked. In your desktop environment a keyring is unlocked when you log-in so it's not a problem until you get into the sterile environment of systemd.  Second, consider moving this service from the system bus to the `--user` bus.  This ssh session may depend on `gpg-agent-ssh.socket` and `gpg-agent.service` which is only available on the `--user` bus.  It will also cause your service to inherit much of your user's environment.

Comment: yes, the key is password protected and managed by the `ssh-agent`. Indeed using an unprotected key it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to fix your specific problem, but you can add verbose output to the ssh command to debug more relating to its use of ssh keys:

```
rsync -avzh \
  -e "ssh -vvv -i /home/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519" \
  /home/localuser/backups/file-to-backup.gz \
  remoteuser@myhost.com:/home/remoteuser/backups
```

The `-vvv` wil make ssh spew a bunch of output to stdout related to the connection, ssh config and ssh keys.  Pipe the output from an interactive run that works to a file and then pipe the output of the service (not working) to a file.  Read both files using a difference utility.  I recommend vimdiff if you are comfortable with vim.  This should at least give you an indication of where something differs and is going wrong.

EDIT: I think rsync defaults to ssh now, and you could put an entry for the remote host in ~/.ssh/config.  This should configure any ssh session (including rsync) to use the provided identity/key and other host specific options you'd like.